# How to syntax highlight inline R code in R Markdown?

Tags: r, syntax-highlighting, knitr, r-markdown

This question is similar to [consistent code html inline and in chunks with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18643863/559676). Instead of .Rhtml documents, I want to highlight inline R code in R Markdown documents, e.g., after `` `r "plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')"` `` is compiled through **rmarkdown**, the tokens like `plot` should be highlighted. By default, R code chunks are syntax highlighted, but there is no way to highlight inline R code.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405536/knitr-inline-chunk-options-no-evaluation-or-just-render-highlighted-code/16406120#16406120

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is one solution using the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/highr) of the **highr** package (`devtools::install_github('yihui/highr')`). Basically you just define your custom LaTeX commands to highlight the tokens. `highr:::cmd_pandoc_latex` is a data frame of LaTeX commands that Pandoc uses to do syntax highlighting.

```
head(highr:::cmd_pandoc_latex)
##                   cmd1 cmd2
## COMMENT  \\CommentTok{    }
## FUNCTION  \\NormalTok{    }
## IF        \\NormalTok{    }
## ELSE      \\NormalTok{    }
## WHILE     \\NormalTok{    }
## FOR       \\NormalTok{    }
```

Then you can redefine the `inline` hook of **knitr**:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
---

```{r include=FALSE}
local({
  hi_pandoc = function(code) {
    if (knitr:::pandoc_to() != 'latex') return(code)
    if (packageVersion('highr') < '0.6.1') stop('highr >= 0.6.1 is required')
    res = highr::hi_latex(code, markup = highr:::cmd_pandoc_latex)
    sprintf('\\texttt{%s}', res)
  }
  hook_inline = knitr::knit_hooks$get('inline')
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
    if (is.character(x) && inherits(x, 'AsIs')) hi_pandoc(x) else hook_inline(x)
  })
})
```

Test inline R code: `r I("plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')")`.
Normal inline code `r pi`.

A code block:

```r
plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')
1 + 2 # a comment
```
````

I used `I()` as a convenient marker to tell the character strings to be syntax highlighted from normal character strings. It is just an arbitrary choice. PDF output:

[image: syntax highlighted inline code]

This is not a perfect solution, though. You will need to tweak it in some cases. For example, most special LaTeX characters are not escaped, such as `~`. You may need to process the LaTeX code returned by `hi_pandoc()` by `gsub()`.

Personally I find multiple colors in inline output distracting, so I would not syntax highlighting it, but this is entirely personal taste.

Comment: One assumes it would be then relatively easy to implement the grey background colour rather than syntax highlighting within the text in the same way. I often find that students reading text with inline code in find it difficult to pick out what is actually R code since the fonts are so similar. Having the grey background would make it clearer, similar I guess to the html output like in your github answer for example.

Comment: Nice solution! Any suggestions how I could highlight the inline code `i %% 5`? The percentage signs are not escaped which throws an error (also inline highlighting a comment like `# Comment` does not work).

Answer (score 17):

Now-a-days:

```
Here is some `plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')`{.R} inline R code
```

Well, I don't know specifically about *R* and the way you're using it, but for most languages (pandoc uses the *skylighting* pkg to do this), you can do inline code blocks with the above syntax.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! Is this feature documented anywhere? I just looked it up in the manual but didn't see it: http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html

Comment: @YihuiXie It seems to be **very** minimally documented [here](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#verbatim). (See in particular the two lines on the `inline_code_attributes` extension.)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Excellent. Thank you very much! I didn't realize that by attaching an attribute of a language name, it could actually enable syntax highlighting.