# How to include mathematical symbols in pseudo code using RMarkdown?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I'm writing up an `rmarkdown` document and I want to include some pseudo code that utilizes the code highlighting feature. I know that if I wanted to include the infinity symbol, I could just use `$\infty$`, but that doesn't work inside of a code chunk. I also realize that I could skip the code chunk since it's pseudo code and use LaTeX, but I'd rather have the code highlighting as a way to differentiate the text from other raw mathematical text in the document.

Is there a way to achieve this? Something like the following code should appear as `D2NN = ∞`.

````
```{r eval=F}
D2NN = $\infty$
```
````

Comment: ```D2NN = ∞``` would work but I guess you're looking for a more generic solution?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme Correct. I'd like to be able to utilize all of the LaTeX symbols inside of an rmarkdown code chunk.

Comment: For what purpose? In a plot? Just to print?

Comment: Just to print. I'm writing notes on an algorithm and want to write the algorithm in pseudo code, but instead of writing something like `D2NN = Inf`, or `sorted_docs = NULL`, I'd rather have `D2NN = $\infty$` or `sorted_docs = $\emptyset$`.

Comment: there might be some workarounds if your target format is pdf (e.g. using xelatex or lualatex, or fancy options in verbatim environments), but generally speaking I think it's best to keep code as plain code.

Comment: You could use Unicode (`'\U221E'`) or `pander` (`pander::pander('$\\infty$')`) or [`latex2exp`](https://github.com/stefano-meschiari/latex2exp) (`plot(latex2exp::TeX('$\\infty$'))`), but it may be easier to use `highr` or `highlight` to highlight the markdown.

Comment: ...or maybe just `cat('$\\infty$')` with `results="asis"` in the chunk options.

Comment: @alistaire The biggest problem with the `pander` and `latex2exp` solutions is that (I believe) it requires the R code to be evaluated. But in order to stick with the pseudo code, we have to prevent the evaluation of the code. If I put all of my code into `plot(latex2exp::TeX(...))`, and change to `eval=TRUE`, I do indeed get my output, but it's not highlighted. Similarly, `highr` seems to only work on R code, and not on mixed code such as R and LaTeX. It's very likely that I'm just doing it wrong, however.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252885/how-to-syntax-highlight-inline-r-code-in-r-markdown) could be adapted. There's also a `highlight` engine for knitr that seems like it might work, but it keeps erroring out for me. Really, though, what you're asking for is a little weird, as you're trying to make the code text change when it runs, which is generally not how knitr works.

Comment: I think the comments have led us more to discussing how to create custom highlighting, and less to my original question, which was about how to use LaTeX variables in code chunks. I agree that it might be a little weird, but also seems like it would be doable.

Comment: @brittenb Could you finally figure this out? And if so, do you mind sharing please?