# Inline code format with knitr and .Rnw

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I use `knitr` to weave my .Rnw documents into .tex and then .pdf document (still using `pdflatex`).

I'm looking for a solution to have the exact same format for inline code and for code chunks. I can use the `texttt{}` function to get the same font, but I am looking for a way to get the exact same format (font, background color, syntax highlighting).

Somebody has an idea?

Comment: You may find some inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/q/40252885/559676. It was for R Markdown. I don't have time to write the solution for Rnw documents, but the idea is the same: redefine the `inline` hook (https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/).

Answer (score 1):

I found the following approximate solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
options(digits = 3, scipen = 6)
some_small_number <- 0.000000000123456
@

  Default math font: \Sexpr{some_small_number}
  Sans-serif font: {\sansmath \Sexpr{some_small_number}}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I would prefer it matches to Helvetica, but at least is it somewhat similar.

UPDATE: Loading `sansmath` after setting default font, `\sfdefault`, does make the math font match the current default (code and image above is corrected for this).

Answer (score 0):

So looking around it does not seem to be possible to change the formatting in inline code, see [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-4.html) and [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/). It seems like if you really want them to look the same you will have to figure out the right latex options if they exist.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Your first reference is for .Rmd documents while I am looking for .Rnw documents. I know I can set the format of the code chunks and of the inline code, I just want to know if there is a way to only define one format and use it both for the chunks and inline code.

Comment: _Can_ you set the format of the inline code? I was not able to find any way to do that, and everything I can see says that it does not take options and matches the output format (except for things like displaying decimals)