# knitr-like (inline) code formatting

Tags: r, latex, knitr

In a `LyX`/`LaTeX` document, I am using `knitr` to include (`R`) code chunks.

I would like to explain my code in below the chunk, by repeating sections of it inline.

How can I achieve the same formatting of text inline (without evaluation)?

There is a question and answer by Yihui on [doing this in `rmarkdown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252885/how-to-syntax-highlight-inline-r-code-in-r-markdown) and another [another answer by him that it should be similar in `LaTeX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252885/how-to-syntax-highlight-inline-r-code-in-r-markdown), but when I try using the code from the `rmarkdown` answer, it throws up errors in `LyX`.

The error I get is:

```
Error in if (knitr:::pandoc_to() != "latex") return(code) : 
argument is of length zero
```

When I remove the `if (knitr ....` line, I get an output document, but the line code is formatted as normal text.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: upon request a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
local({
  hi_pandoc = function(code) {
    if (knitr:::pandoc_to() != 'latex') return(code)
    if (packageVersion('highr') < '0.6.1') stop('highr >= 0.6.1 is required')
    res = highr::hi_latex(code, markup = highr:::cmd_pandoc_latex)
    sprintf('\\texttt{%s}', res)
  }
  hook_inline = knitr::knit_hooks$get('inline')
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
    if (is.character(x) && inherits(x, 'AsIs')) hi_pandoc(x) else hook_inline(x)
  })
})
@

Test inline R code: \Sexpr{ I("plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')") }.
Normal inline code \Sexpr{pi}.

A code block:

<<>>=
plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')
1 + 2 # a comment
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: It's the same code as the rmarkdown, but in LyX so that's sort of verbose. I will add something in LaTeX that should be equivalent.

Comment: Your MWE compiles when I replace `\Sexpr{r pi}` with `\Sexpr{pi}`. Which part of the produced output do you want changed?

Comment: ah thanks for catching that, it doesn't compile for me

Comment: is the `plot(cars, ...` formatted similar to knitr chunks?

Comment: For me, the two code blocks are formatted with a fixed width (typewriter) font, while the two inline code blocks use the normal text font.

Comment: ok thank you, so I guess it doesn't work correctly then, could you also please tell me what you knit command was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<include=FALSE>>=
local({
  hi_pandoc = function(code) {
    if (packageVersion('highr') < '0.6.1') stop('highr >= 0.6.1 is required')
    res = highr::hi_latex(code, markup = highr:::cmd_latex)
    sprintf('\\texttt{%s}', res)
  }
  hook_inline = knitr::knit_hooks$get('inline')
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
    if (is.character(x) && inherits(x, 'AsIs')) hi_pandoc(x) else hook_inline(x)
  })
})
@

Test inline R code: \Sexpr{ I("plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')") }.
Normal inline code \Sexpr{pi}.

A code block:

<<>>=
plot(cars, main = 'A scatterplot.')
1 + 2 # a comment
@

\end{document}
```

I removed the `knitr:::pandoc_to` and replaced `highr:::cmd_pandoc_latex` with `highr:::cmd_latex` since you are not using `pandoc`. Result:

[image]

Comment: fantastic! thanks so much. Although this does mean that I have to get back to writing now :-| :-D

Comment: maybe it would be useful if highr 0.6.1 can to CRAN

Comment: @Bastiaan You could open an issue on GitHub and ask for a CRAN release.