# consistent code formatting inline and in chunks with bookdown

Tags: knitr, bookdown

For `bookdown`, I'm working on recreating inline code formatting that is similar to what is produced in chunks (see this [old SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643863/consistent-code-html-inline-and-in-chunks-with-knitr)). My current approach is:

```
local({
  hook_old <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("inline")  
  knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x, options) {
    if (is.character(x) & knitr::is_html_output()) {
      highr::hi_html(x)
    } else {
      hook_old(x, options)
    }
  })
})
```

but that produces an empty html file for the chapter that attempts to use

```
`r 'lm(y ~ x, data = dat)'`
```

There is a reproducible repo at [`topepo/bookdown-inline`](https://github.com/topepo/bookdown-inline); see `01-intro.Rmd`.

Generally, I suspect that the whole approach is different in `bookdown`.

Comment: I think this problem is possible to solve. Which output formats do you want the syntax highlighting to work with? I haven't tested it, but I guess HTML might be a little easier. LaTeX might be trickier, but shouldn't be terribly hard.

Comment: HTML is the main one. Thanks